# Xbox API usage PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've been using xapi.us in order to get my clips from XBL using their API, using this code below I've managed to get a result on my page...

```
<?php 
$uxid = rawurlencode("PROFILE ID");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xapi.us/v2/{$uxid}/game-clips");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "X-Auth: API KEY",
]);

$info = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo $info
?>
```

This is the result which I belive Is JSON...

```
[{
    "gameClipId": "34aabe8a-0d04-4940-81cd-d3fb20916c8c",
    "state": "Published",
    "datePublished": "2021-01-14T03:24:21.462109Z",
    "dateRecorded": "2021-01-14 01:59:00",
    "lastModified": "2021-01-14 03:24:21",
    "userCaption": "",
    "type": "UserGenerated",
    "durationInSeconds": 29,
    "scid": "d1adc8aa-0a31-4407-90f2-7e9b54b0347c",
    "titleId": 175227487,
    "rating": 0,
    "ratingCount": 0,
    "views": 0,
    "titleData": "",
    "systemProperties": "260d3869-a9ce-4942-ac54-79f6456773d10;",
    "savedByUser": true,
    "achievementId": "",
    "greatestMomentId": "",
    "thumbnails": [
      {
        "uri": "https://gameclipscontent-t2015.xboxlive.com/xuid-2533275001057958-public/34aabe8a-0d04-4940-81cd-d3fb20916c8c_Thumbnail.PNG",
        "fileSize": 0,
        "thumbnailType": "Small"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://gameclipscontent-t2015.xboxlive.com/xuid-2533275001057958-public/34aabe8a-0d04-4940-81cd-d3fb20916c8c_Thumbnail.PNG",
        "fileSize": 0,
        "thumbnailType": "Large"
      }
    ],
    "gameClipUris": [
      {
        "uri": "https://gameclipscontent-d2015.xboxlive.com/xuid-2533275001057958-private/34aabe8a-0d04-4940-81cd-d3fb20916c8c.MP4?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&si=DefaultAccess&sig=rVMEhFFUBNs0CZ%2BDMZoKiSvHHEWjpFcGSfvCR5XmLH4%3D&__gda__=1610684218_953e590c0692005ef4655d3c29afa051",
        "fileSize": 53206064,
        "uriType": "Download",
        "expiration": "2021-01-15 04:16:58"
      }
    ],
    "xuid": 2533275001057958,
    "clipName": "",
    "titleName": "Apex Legends™",
    "gameClipLocale": "en-GB",
    "clipContentAttributes": "None",
    "deviceType": "Scarlett",
    "commentCount": 0,
    "likeCount": 0,
    "shareCount": 0,
    "partialViews": 0,
    "gameClipDetails": "https://xapi.us/v2/2533275001057958/game-clip-details/d1adc8aa-0a31-4407-90f2-7e9b54b0347c/34aabe8a-0d04-4940-81cd-d3fb20916c8c"
  }]
```

How would I go about getting just the gameClipUris.uri ? I've tried echo `$gameClipUris.uri` but I'm not entirely sure what I'm meant to be doing here I'm just googling around seeing if anything works.

EDIT:

I've tried this and still no avail.

```
    <?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$uxid = rawurlencode("2533275001057958");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xapi.us/v2/{$uxid}/game-clips");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "X-Auth: API Key",
]);

$info = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

$clip = json_decode($info);

echo $clip->gameClipId;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON contains an array of objects (in this case, an array with one object). `gameClipUris` is also an array:

```
$clip = json_decode($info);
echo $clip[0]->gameClipUris[0]->uri; // expected output
```

Use `print_r()` to read your variables in a human-readable way, it helps a lot.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: That's worked thanks, is there a way to make it return all gameClipUris ? as there's a few.

Comment: sussed it I'll update my question with extra info for those who want to use it thanks!